# mysql not starting after removing plasma-desktop

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql, kde

I know there are many questions regarding mysql not starting. I've tried following things

Checking MySQL error log — `error reading '/var/log/mysql': Is a directory`

Check `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` file for broken packages again no such file or directory

Remove MySQL-server and reinstall it But it's not getting uninstalled at all

this problem occurred when I uninstalled "plasma-desktop". I used following commands to remove "plasma-desktop" and related packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge '^kde' '^kubuntu' '^plasma'

sudo apt-get remove plasma-desktop

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

There was no error produced by the above three commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql\*
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -r /etc/mysql
sudo updatedb
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-common
```

Then reinstall MySQL

```
sudo apt-get -f install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" mysql-server
```

Comment: I guess the source of this answer was https://serverfault.com/a/526702/372359 ? Be sure to give proper attribution as mentioned [here in our Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/referencing)